# How to convert any Object to String?

Tags: java, android, string, android-fragments, valueconverter

Here is my code:

```
for (String toEmail : toEmailList)          
{
    Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmail);
    emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));      
}
```

Please give me some suggestion about this.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question, which object?

Answer (score 77):

To convert any object to string there are several methods in Java

```
String convertedToString = String.valueOf(Object);  //method 1

String convertedToString = "" + Object;   //method 2

String convertedToString = Object.toString();  //method 3
```

**I would prefer the first and third**

**EDIT**
If working in kotlin, the official android language

```
val number: Int = 12345
String convertAndAppendToString = "number = $number"   //method 1

String convertObjectMemberToString = "number = ${Object.number}" //method 2

String convertedToString = Object.toString()  //method 3
```

Comment: Object.toString() can throws NPE

Comment: ```String.valueOf``` ends up calling ```toString()``` anyway, but it does do a null check.

Comment: Completely forgot about String.valueOf()

Answer (score 9):

If the class does not have `toString()` method, then you can use `ToStringBuilder` class from [org.apache.commons:commons-lang3](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang)

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(yourObject)
```

Answer (score 5):

I've written a few methods for **convert** by **Gson** library and **java 1.8** .

thay are daynamic model for convert.

string to object

object to string

List to string

string to List

HashMap to String

String to JsonObj

```
//saeedmpt 
public static String convertMapToString(Map<String, String> data) {
    //convert Map  to String
    return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data);
}
public static <T> List<T> convertStringToList(String strListObj) {
    //convert string json to object List
    return new Gson().fromJson(strListObj, new TypeToken<List<Object>>() {
    }.getType());
}
public static <T> T convertStringToObj(String strObj, Class<T> classOfT) {
    //convert string json to object
    return new Gson().fromJson(strObj, (Type) classOfT);
}

public static JsonObject convertStringToJsonObj(String strObj) {
    //convert string json to object
    return new Gson().fromJson(strObj, JsonObject.class);
}

public static <T> String convertListObjToString(List<T> listObj) {
    //convert object list to string json for
    return new Gson().toJson(listObj, new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
    }.getType());
}

public static String convertObjToString(Object clsObj) {
    //convert object  to string json
    String jsonSender = new Gson().toJson(clsObj, new TypeToken<Object>() {
    }.getType());
    return jsonSender;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"toString()" is Very useful method which returns a string representation of an object. The "toString()" method returns a string reperentation an object.It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Declaration: java.lang.Object.toString()

Since, you have not mentioned which object you want to convert, so I am just using any object in sample code.

```
Integer integerObject = 5;
String convertedStringObject = integerObject .toString();
System.out.println(convertedStringObject );
```

You can find the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaheshKapoor/935f0baa7b95a7b83001).
You can test the code [here](http://ideone.com/glDQeN).

Answer (score 3):

I am try to convert Object type variable into string using this line of code

try this to convert object value to string:

**Java Code**

```
 Object dataobject=value;
    //convert object into String  
     String convert= String.valueOf(dataobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question properly but as per your heading, you can convert any type of object to string by using `toString()` function on a `String` Object.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```java
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 String oldSerial = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```