# Append double quotes in nested json string - Java

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a nested json string like below for which I need to append double quotes for each key and value

> {messageFilters:[{filterCriteria:[{paramNameAndVals:{},values:[abc[0-9]],context:Request,name:Destination-Host,operator:abc}],filterActions:[{paramNameAndVals:{Set
>   Name:sdf,Value To
>   Hash:as},context:Context,name:Stick-To-Pool}],name:MF}],name:fg1,subGroups:[],advancedView:false}

I want below output like ,

> {"messageFilters":[{"filterCriteria":[{"paramNameAndVals":{},"values":["abc[0-9]"],"context":"Request","name":"Destination-Host","operator":"abc"}],"filterActions":[{"paramNameAndVals":{"Set
>   Name":"sdf","Value To
>   Hash":"as"},"context":"Context","name":"Stick-To-Pool"}],"name":"MF"}],"name":"fg1","subGroups":[],"advancedView":false}

I tried various regex patterns, but evrerything in vain. Could anyone please help

Comment: how are you creating your json?

Comment: Json is created through CDL.toString() method.
The above json is actually an inner class, I am trying to import CSV file which has other columns as well and this is one of the column value and CDL.toString() is returning the entire value as json string .

Comment: what on earth is CDL?

Comment: org.json.CDL is the package and it provides various static methods to convert CSV to jsonArray and vice-versa.

Comment: I cannot change the design right now as i have to support backward comaptibility.
All I am looking for is a regex which will help me achieve this !

Comment: as per javadocs *This provides static methods to convert comma delimited text into a JSONArray, and to covert a JSONArray into comma delimited text.*

Comment: Ok basically first we are exporting the data in CSV format and output gives me as json only for inner class . And when I try to import it back I want to convert the json string in question to actual json object ,I tried using Gson, passing the string as constructor parameter for JSONObject for all trials I am getting parse exception for ",values:[abc[0-9]] " this parameter. Hence I need to effectively append double quotes in order to convert it into JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

the first example of your question is not a valid json, try convert your not valid json to string.
kindly chechk this link for more information
[How to convert any Object to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847080/how-to-convert-any-object-to-string)

Comment: That json is generated through CDL.toString() method.